Running R shiny apps within Docker containers - additional package installation
I was hoping for a bit of guidance with use of Docker to deploy R shiny apps within my organisation. I can't find an answer to this elsewhere - apologies if it exists already and if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.
The idea was to package R shiny apps as Docker containers, so that coworkers with Docker desktop installed can then run these on their local machine without requiring R installed etc.
I was wondering how installation of software is approached with Docker - I know that Docker containers can install R libraries and packages, but would this be done only the first time a container is run, or would it be performed every time it is used? Also, how feasible would it be to pre-install additional packages within the container? I am aware that rocker contains images with e.g. tidyverse installed - but how would one go about adding additional packages for more bespoke applications?
Thanks very much for any guidance here, my knowledge of Docker is only pretty rudimentary at this stage but just wanted to get an idea of how this could potentially be employed.


Typically you install software in an image when it's built.  You would not generally install software into a running container, since that will be lost as soon as the container exits.  You can build your own image starting from any preëxisting image you want, running whatever commands you need to install things.

Please see this or this.
